# How to ignore DTD validation in apache's DOMParser?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xerces

Using apaches DOMParser `(org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser)` Implementation,
We can supress DTD validation by using the following feature:

```
parser.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
```

But this will remove the DTD declaration from the xml itself. If you print the xml in string format, you will see that the original DTD declaration in the XML file is missing.  What can be a fix to this problem? Even something like this:
1. load the document.
2. extract the dtd declaration.
3. suppress dtd validation (DTD declaration removed).
4. parse and update document.
5. add the DTD declaration once again.

Comment: How about using a simple regex to extract it? `<!DOCTYPE[^>]+>`

Comment: @JLRishe: That would be crude :(  but it would still be helpful if you provide the regular expression to retain the DOCTYPE.

Comment: I already did.  You would first perform a regex Match to locate the matching text and set it aside for safekeeping, and then perform a regex Replace to eliminate it from the original XML string.